# SELECT FROM EXECUTE without INSERT permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server

My company uses software that I can write queries into but we don't have permission to use keywords like `CREATE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE`.

So I have a set of results that I acquire by using `EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql` on a variable that contains some dynamic sql and I need to be able to `JOIN` the results of that command to a previously existing query. Since I cannot use `INSERT`, I **cannot** do something like the following:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE ([column definitions here])

INSERT INTO @temp 
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

SELECT ...
JOIN @temp
```

With that being said, does anyone have an alternative solution?

Comment: Nope. You have to define the table first to be able to insert into a table. Or if you can change the contents of @SQL you could use "select into" inside the dynamic sql.

Comment: yes. try "select into"

Comment: You  can talk to your superior to give a right permission according to your needs.

Comment: @SeanLange the content within the dynamic sql is Out of Scope from the rest of the page, so I can't access temp tables with "select into" from inside of them.

Comment: @reds the problem isn't with my company, it's the 3rd-party closed-source software we've paid to use.

Comment: I figured you couldn't use temp tables. You would have to use select into a persistent table and then drop it later. Or make it a global temp table. Regardless this situation is just ugly and nothing you can do is going to be super.

Comment: I can't use CREATE so anything other than a table variable is out of the question. Yeah, the situation is ugly and most of my department is scratching their heads.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `OPENROWSET` to execute the procedure and wrap it in a select.

```
SELECT * INTO @TMyTable FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
    'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'EXEC dbo.MyStoredProc'
);
```

Adjust the connection string if needed.

You can JOIN the other tables to the `OPENROWSET` result directly, in that case you don't need INSERT privileges (and the SELECT...INTO construct).

Please note that `Ad Hoc Distributed Queries` has to be enabled on the server to do so.

```
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Also please note, that a Stored Procedure can produce more than one result sets. In this case, `OPENROWSET` will return only the first one.

Another catch is that if you want to provide parameters to this, the query will be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, therefore this method should be used with care.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try this out. Not sure if I can learn the connection string since I'm only able to run this query from within the software's UI. Also that last sentence makes me very nervous.